# Odoo custom addon_path not found

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I setup a clean Debian 10 vps, launch this setup script
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yenthe666/InstallScript/14.0/odoo_install_debian.sh

and all seems is correctly installed

I can't get the /odoo/custom/addons folder to work

Odoo Enterprise

This is the /etc/odoo-server.conf

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = xxxxxxxxxx
xmlrpc_port = 8069
logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo-server.log
addons_path = /odoo/enterprise/addons,/odoo/odoo-server/addons,/odoo/custom/addons
proxy_mode = True
```

then

```
service odoo-server restart
```

checking on the log the directory is found

```
2020-11-18 09:32:46,144 4683 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/odoo/odoo-server/odoo/addons', 
'/odoo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/14.0', '/odoo/enterprise/addons', '/odoo/odoo-server/addons', 
'/odoo/custom/addons']
```

All modules inside /odoo/custom/addons have correct permissions "odoo:odoo" and 755

Activated developer mode with assets
In apps menu clicked on update module list

New addon doesn't show in App list...  :(

Same addon here /odoo/odoo-server/addons works

Comment: did you update the apps list?

Comment: Yes sure apps list refreshed

Answer (score 2):

Before all things, change permissions using:

```
sudo chmod -R odoo:odoo /added_path_of_addons/
```

Stop server using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server stop
```

Then restart it again:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/odoo-server start
```

Answer (score 0):

pic1:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yn29N.png)
pic1 stop and start servise odoo after check pic2
odoo---server---odoo.conf---addons_path:Give the address your module want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yrjNJ.png)